# how to grant an API permission in C# via graph to an AppReg

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

In C# on .NET Core 7, I use MS Graph to add an appreg (App registrations) to Azure.

When I create this appreg, I add the "client secret" and an API Permission to it in the same call.

Everything works perfectly well, I see my appreg in Azure with its secret and the role available in the API that this appreg (the client in my case) calls.

But, unfortunately, the role is not "grant".

I can't find any information on the MS site about how to "grant" this role with Graph. Has anyone solved this problem ?

This is my code. For this example, let's assume that the API Client ID is : "0001".

For this example, let's assume that the Client ID (the one created via the code) is : "0002".

For this example, let's assume that the API Role I would like to attach to my appreg has the Client ID : "0003".

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GetGraphServiceClientAsync();
Application requestBody = new()
        {
            DisplayName = "MyNewAppReg",
            Description = "MyNewAppReg - created by me",
            RequiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>
            {
                new()
                {
                    ResourceAppId = "0001",
                    ResourceAccess = new List<ResourceAccess>
                    {
                        new()
                        {
                            Id =  Guid.Parse("0003"),
                            Type = "Role"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
Application? result = await graphClient.Applications.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

On the MS site there is this, but it doesn't work, I think it's not about how to add a permission to a client but more to the API itself.

```
var permission = new AppRoleAssignment
        {
            PrincipalId = Guid.Parse("0001"),
            ResourceId = Guid.Parse("0002"),
            AppRoleId = Guid.Parse("0003")
        };

var result = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["0002"].AppRoleAssignments.GetAsync();
```

When the code reaches this line

```
var result = .....
```

I get an error:

> ODataError.error.Code = Request_ResourceNotFound
> ODataError.error.Message = Resource '0002' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

FYI : '0002' does exist

Answer (score 0):

There is only a API where you can read the list of consent requests but there aren't any methods to programmatically approve or deny a request.

Resources:

[Consent request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/consentrequests-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[List app consent requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/appconsentapprovalroute-list-appconsentrequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[List user consent requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/userconsentrequest?view=graph-rest-1.0)